# Blackberry simulator having DNS exception

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I have been running my blackberry app on the simulator. I have use deviceside=true behind the url. However, when i run it now it is giving me an exception net.rim.device.cldc.io.dns.DNSException: DNS error

What has happened? I haven't change the code or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It possible the state of the computer you are running this on has changed. E.g. in terms of connectivity (which would explain the exception).

Comment: How do I change it back? I am using a LAN connection. Don't think it will change that much?

Comment: I don't really understand. When I turn on my wifi, it started running again. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: It is possible that your OS has a problem with choosing the right connection to use.

Comment: It could be that. I am not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that:

1.) If deviceside=true is specified in the connection URI, a direct TCP connection is opened from the handheld, without using the Mobile Data Service.

2.) If deviceside=false is specified in the connection URI, a proxy TCP connection is opened using the Mobile Data Service.

3.) If the deviceside parameter is not specified the behaviour varies by platform: on a BlackBerry 6500 or 7500 handheld, direct TCP is used by default; on all other handhelds, the Mobile Data Service is used by default, and if an MDS is not available the handheld falls back on direct TCP.

I was getting this error simply because the DNS name I used didn't resolve. Bad setting in the bind9 config.